# Asterisk max calls

Tags: asterisk, function-calls, pjsua2

I am trying to do a stress test on the asterisk server.
I have created multiple accounts that call each other.

For example

```
1001 calls -----> 1002
1003 calls -----> 1004
1005 calls -----> 1006
```

Somehow when the server gets to 64 active calls it keeps saying that there is no active port.
And I can't make any more calls.

The error log;

```
Choices:
   0         For current dialog.
  -1         All 0 buddies in buddy list
  [1 - 0]    Select from buddy list
  URL        An URL
  <Enter>    Empty input (or 'q') to cancel
Make call: 07:40:28.584   pjsua_call.c !Making call with acc #1 to sip:1006@127.0.0.1:25060
07:40:28.584    pjsua_aud.c  .Set sound device: capture=-99, playback=-99
07:40:28.584    pjsua_aud.c  ..Setting null sound device..
07:40:28.584    pjsua_app.c  ...Turning sound device ON
07:40:28.584    pjsua_aud.c  ...Opening null sound device..
07:40:28.584  pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: initializing media..
07:40:28.584  pjsua_media.c  ..Unable to find appropriate RTP/RTCP ports combination
07:40:28.584  pjsua_media.c  ..Unable to create RTP/RTCP socket: Address already in use [status=120098]
07:40:28.584  pjsua_media.c  ..Error creating media transport: Address already in use
07:40:28.584   pjsua_call.c  .Error initializing media channel: Address already in use [status=120098]
07:40:28.584  pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: deinitializing media..
>>> >>>>
Account list:
  [ 0] <sip:172.31.31.91:30404>: does not register
       Online status: Online
 *[ 1] sip:1005@172.31.31.91: 200/OK (expires=219)
       Online status: Online
Buddy list:
 -none-
```

Anybody a clue why this keeps happening.
I have also created a script that registers 5000 users, all with different ports and this works perfectly without any problems. Would it be possible that there is somewhere a limit function?

Answer (score 1):

Likly you have limited number of ports allowed in rtp.conf file

Please stop spam same questions, asterisk for sure can handle thousands of calls, check your setup(embeded?)/config.

Comment: Seems like it has nothing to do with the rtp.conf file. I have tried this by changing it to beginning port 10000 and endport 30000, but the calls keep the same. The server allows all ports at this moment for testing, but this seems also not to work. Somehow it can just take a minimum of ports.

Comment: You need restart server to affect changes in rtp.conf. Anyway, what you asking require DEBUG, which is offtopic on SO.